# wirless hotspot in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hot-spot

hi friends am using ubuntu 14.04 and am tired of searching software to make my laptop a hotspot i tried installing ap-hotspot but when i type sudo ap-hotspot start ,it freezes and when i type sudo ap-hotspot stop ,it displays not in active .so please help what is a best way to fix it.i even tried this

```
cd /tmp
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

note:I want this wifi for my android mobile